# Why is this `cp` command trying to remove files?

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on a Dell 50-50 laptop. Everything went fine until:

```
[1635][lam@ubuntu:~/bin]$ ll
total 48
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam  232 Jan 27 20:37 demo.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam   34 Aug 26 22:02 encore.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam   94 Nov 13 16:54 esame.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam  156 Jan 20 14:21 ginfo.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam   61 Oct 31 15:56 hello_world.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam 2323 Jan 20 13:36 infoscript
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lam lam  257 Dec  4 17:22 local-variable
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lam lam   16 Jan 28 15:2[1638]
[lam@ubuntu:~/bin]$ cp sayH.sh temp/sayH2.sh~
rm: cannot remove `sayH.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `temp/sayH2.sh~': No such file or directory
```

I am trying to copy a file, yet Ubuntu apparently tries to remove it. Can anybody explain it?

Comment: Welcome Lam to Ask Ubuntu! I have edited your question, so that it's more readable, and the title is more likely to grab other's attention.

Comment: check your `aliasses` with the command `alias`.

Comment: Check the following:1)Have you set an alias for `cp` in `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`? 2)You have no folder `temp` in your current directory, so do you mean /temp? 3) What is the purpose of `~` in your destination?

Comment: Using `--remove-destination`? ... See `man cp`. And I would suggest `type cp` (assuming default Bash) instead of `alias`, because it could be a function, too.

Answer (score 1):

@rafalcieslak
Thank you for your help.I had searched for the wrong alias(`cp=rm -i`) only in bashrc & it was not there. following your advice I tried `alias` on CLI & there it was the misfit.
Unaliasing it did it.

Comment: who told you that? >:)